# JAXB binding schema of dtd file

Tags: jaxb, dtd

A noobie question. I am generating Java code from a dtd file (USPTO dtd). The DTD specifies the root element as follows:

```
<!ELEMENT us-patent-grant (doc-page+ | (us-bibliographic-data-grant , abstract* , drawings? , description , us-sequence-list-doc? , us-megatable-doc?,table-external-doc* , us-chemistry* , us-math* ,us-claim-statement , claims))>
```

When I run xjc with the following binding schema

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xml-java-binding-schema version="1.0ea2">
       <element name="us-patent-grant" type="class" root="true"></element>
    </xml-java-binding-schema>
```

I see the following Java object generated

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "docPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "us-patent-grant")
    public class UsPatentGrant {
       ....

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "doc-page", required = true, type = DocPage.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-bibliographic-data-grant", required = true, type = UsBibliographicDataGrant.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "abstract", required = true, type = Abstract.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "drawings", required = true, type = Drawings.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "description", required = true, type = Description.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-sequence-list-doc", required = true, type = UsSequenceListDoc.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-megatable-doc", required = true, type = UsMegatableDoc.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "table-external-doc", required = true, type = TableExternalDoc.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-chemistry", required = true, type = UsChemistry.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-math", required = true, type = UsMath.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "us-claim-statement", required = true, type = UsClaimStatement.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "claims", required = true, type = Claims.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> docPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims;

     .........

public List<Object> getDocPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims() {
    if (docPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims == null) {
        docPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.docPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims;
}
```

So my question is how can i change the name of the long getter

```
getDocPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims
```

in the binding schema?

thank you in advance.

Comment: I think the supplied code is enough. I'm coming to the conclusion that this isn't possible with DTD and jaxb binding customisation

Comment: For now I've converted the DTD and edited the resulting xsd

Answer (score 2):

This isn't so much an answer as evidence for what you are suspecting.

In the [JAXB/XJC](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/tree/master/jaxb-ri/xjc) source for `com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.dtd.Element`, in the [bind()](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/blob/f1ef0676987b83b134b8c97fe99083423f7f3311/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/dtd/Element.java#L290) method, you can see this excerpt, iterating through the child `elements` of the `Element`:

```
if(b.isRepeated || b.elements.size()>1) {
    // collection
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    for( Element e : b.elements ) {
        if(name.length()>0)
            name.append("Or");
        name.append(owner.model.getNameConverter().toPropertyName(e.name));
    }
    ...
} else {
    // single property
    String name = b.elements.iterator().next().name;
            String propName = owner.model.getNameConverter().toPropertyName(name);
            ...
}
```

That looks like it offers little opportunity to change the sequence of `"Or"` separators where there are multiple child elements.

You can see the `bindInfo` allowing custom names elsewhere in `Element`, but not near here.  Unless someone else can spot it, the chances to rename things seem to end there.  In short, the `CElementPropertyInfo` this outputs leads to `BeanGenerator.fields`, which lead to `JDefinedClass.fields` which are then output directly by `JDefinedClass.declareBody()`.

As the [XJC docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html#CHDHFFIJ) say, DTD support is still experimental...

Comment: Thanks for the details ...  indeed DTD support is "experimental and unsupported" ... I'm going to have to try to convince the 3rd party I'm trying to integrate with to get out of the 90s ;)

Comment: That is extraordinarily kind for a non-answer, thank you.  I was thinking of suggesting a bit of search/replace on the generated files in the build script next, to make the changes the bindings don't support. Though to be fair, that too feels like a throw back to the 90s.

Comment: Wow, if this is the stackoverlow response to a dtd question I'll just take a step back

Answer (score 2):

As @df778899 mentioned, if you looked at the below source code then nothing much can be done about it

```
CElementPropertyInfo p;
if(b.isRepeated || b.elements.size()>1) {
    // collection
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    for( Element e : b.elements ) {
        if(name.length()>0)
            name.append("Or");
        name.append(owner.model.getNameConverter().toPropertyName(e.name));
    }
    p = new CElementPropertyInfo(name.toString(), REPEATED_ELEMENT, ID.NONE, null, null,null/*TODO*/, locator, !b.isOptional );
    for( Element e : b.elements ) {
        CClassInfo child = owner.getOrCreateElement(e.name).getClassInfo();
        assert child!=null; // we are requiring them to be classes.
        p.getTypes().add(new CTypeRef(child,new QName("",e.name),null,false,null));
    }
```

The `CElementPropertyInfo` object takes the name and the only way to fix is to use instrumentation. So I created a maven project

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.tarunlalwani</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxc-customizer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/libs
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Premain-Class>com.xjc.javaagent.SimpleAgent</Premain-Class>
                        <Boot-Class-Path>libs/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar</Boot-Class-Path>
                        <Class-Path>libs/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>

                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**jxccustomizer/src/main/java/com/xjc/javaagent/SimpleAgent.java**

```
package com.xjc.javaagent;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class SimpleAgent {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs,
                               Instrumentation instrumentation){

        System.out.println("Starting Agent");
        SimpleClassFileTransformer transformer =
                new SimpleClassFileTransformer();
        instrumentation.addTransformer(transformer);
    }
}
```

**jxccustomizer/src/main/java/com/xjc/javaagent/SimpleClassFileTransformer.java**

```
package com.xjc.javaagent;

import javassist.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class SimpleClassFileTransformer implements
        ClassFileTransformer {

    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                            String className, Class classBeingRedefined,
                            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
            throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;
        if (className.endsWith("/CPropertyInfo")) {
            System.out.println("Loading class - " + className);
            try {
                ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
                CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
                CtConstructor[] constructors = ctClass.getConstructors();
                for (CtConstructor c : constructors) {
                    c.insertBefore("{        String propFile = System.getProperty(\"XJC_REMAP\");\n" +
                            "        if (propFile != null)\n" +
                            "        {\n" +
                            "            System.out.println(\"External remap file provided\");\n" +
                            "            java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();\n" +
                            "            try {\n" +
                            "                props.load(new java.io.FileInputStream(propFile));\n" +
                            "                java.util.Enumeration enums = props.propertyNames();\n" +
                            "                while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {\n" +
                            "                    String key = (String)enums.nextElement();\n" +
                            "                    String value = props.getProperty(key);\n" +
                            "                    try {\n" +
                            "                        System.out.println(\"Checking if \" + name + \" matches \" + key);\n" +
                            "                        java.util.regex.Pattern pat = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(\"^\" + key +\"$\", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);\n" +
                            "                        if (pat.matcher(name).find())\n" +
                            "                        {\n" +
                            "                            System.out.println(\"Replacing \" + name + \" with \" + value);\n" +
                            "                            name = value;\n" +
                            "                            break;\n" +
                            "                        }\n" +
                            "                    } finally {\n" +
                            "                        if (name == key) {\n" +
                            "                            System.out.println(\"Replacing \" + name + \" with \" + value);\n" +
                            "                            name = value;\n" +
                            "                        }\n" +
                            "                        break;\n" +
                            "                    }\n" +
                            "                }\n" +
                            "            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {\n" +
                            "                e.printStackTrace();\n" +
                            "            }\n" +
                            "        }}");
                }
                byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                ctClass.detach();
                System.out.println("NO Exception occured");
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return byteCode;
    }
}
```

The above class can load a properties file specified by `-DXJC_REMAP=<filepath>` which will be of below format

**remap.properties**

```
docPageOr.*=patentDocument
```

Now to test the solution. First need to generated the `jar` for the agent by running below command

```
mvn clean package
```

Next is to create some testing `dtd`

**binding.xjb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-java-binding-schema>
    <options package="org"/>
    <element name="us-patent-grant" type="class" root="true"></element>
</xml-java-binding-schema>
```

**testing.dtd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- DTD to write simple stories
      Made by Daniel K. Schneider / TECFA / University of Geneva
      VERSION 1.0
      30/10/2003 -->
<!ELEMENT us-patent-grant (doc-page+ | (us-bibliographic-data-grant , abstract* , drawings? , description , us-sequence-list-doc? , us-megatable-doc?,table-external-doc* , us-chemistry* , us-math* ,us-claim-statement , claims))>
```

Now to use this to run the agent with `xjc`

```
$ export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/tarunlalwani.com/tarunlalwani/workshop/ub16/so/jaxb/jxccustomizer/target/jxc-customizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DXJC_REMAP=/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/tarunlalwani.com/tarunlalwani/workshop/ub16/so/jaxb/remap.properties"

$ xjc -b binding.xjb -dtd testing.dtd
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/tarunlalwani.com/tarunlalwani/workshop/ub16/so/jaxb/jxccustomizer/target/jxc-customizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DXJC_REMAP=/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/tarunlalwani.com/tarunlalwani/workshop/ub16/so/jaxb/remap.properties
objc[33035]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/xjc (0x10ed964c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10eded4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Starting Agent
Loading class 2 - com/sun/tools/internal/xjc/model/CPropertyInfo
inside try
Updating cons 1
Updating cons
NO Exception occured
parsing a schema...
External remap file provided
Checking if DocPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims matches docPageOr.*
Replacing DocPageOrUsBibliographicDataGrantOrAbstractOrDrawingsOrDescriptionOrUsSequenceListDocOrUsMegatableDocOrTableExternalDocOrUsChemistryOrUsMathOrUsClaimStatementOrClaims with patentDocument
compiling a schema...
org/Abstract.java
org/Claims.java
org/Description.java
org/DocPage.java
org/Drawings.java
org/ObjectFactory.java
org/TableExternalDoc.java
org/UsBibliographicDataGrant.java
org/UsChemistry.java
org/UsClaimStatement.java
org/UsMath.java
org/UsMegatableDoc.java
org/UsPatentGrant.java
org/UsSequenceListDoc.java
```

And now the content of generated file is as desired

[image: Correct generated output]

The git repo for the above code is available on below link

https://github.com/tarunlalwani/xjc-java-agent-customization